# Using ListViewPrinter of ObjectListView.

Tags: objectlistview

I have read about ListViewPrinter of ObjectListView and I would like to use its features to print data from FastDataListView. I am using the version 2.9.1072 of ObjectListView. However, there is no where I see ListViewPrinter in ObjectListView classes, that is, in the BrightIdeasSoftware namespace. May someone please direct me on how to get the ListViewPrinter in my project.

Comment: The ListViewPrinter is not in the `ObjectListView.dll`. You have to additionally reference the `ListViewPrinter.dll`.

Comment: Thanks @Rev1.0. Where maybe - can I get the ListViewPrinter.dll. I have looked around and I do not see anything. I downloaded the ObjectListView demo from sourgeForge and even there my demos they dont compile because i do not have the ListViewPrinter.dll. Maybe you please send me a link where I can download it. Thank you once again.